# jquery-ias not loading anything

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ias

I am using jquery-ias.min.js for producing an infinite scrol in my page but the plugin is not displaying anything..
Just the message that "there are no more pages left to load"?
i am using this code.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layout/js/jquery-ias.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ias = $.ias({
        container: "#posts",
        item: ".post",
        pagination: "#pagination",
        next: ".next a"
    });
    ias.extension(new IASSpinnerExtension());
    ias.extension(new IASTriggerExtension({
        offset: 2
    }));
    ias.extension(new IASNoneLeftExtension({
        text: 'There are no more pages left to load.'
    }));
</script>
```

Comment: Please, put your html code

Answer (score 0):

The response `there are no more pages left to load` means the next page doesn't exists.
Check if your `next` selector (`.next a`) is correct, maybe it is not getting the link. If the selector is correct, check your server response for the next page.

**Update**
Your html:

```
<div id="pagination"> 
    <a class="" href="/highlights-1" >2</a> 
    <a class="next" href="/page2.html" >1</a> 
</div>
```

Your selector to get the next link is invalid, if you try `$('.next a')` the result will be an empty array. The correct is just `.next`.
Change your initialization to:

```
var ias = $.ias({
    ...
    next: ".next"
});
```

Comment: <div id="pagination">
<a class="" href="/highlights-1" >2</a>
<a class="next" href="/page2.html" >1</a>
 </div>

Comment: these are the links i am using

Comment: i tried your solution but it is still not working...now its not displaying anything but a message that "load more items"

Comment: anybody please tell me what to do here..@vcarvalho

Comment: In your page there are no `.next` links (ex: `<a href="..." class="next"`), all your links are with the class attribute empty. The problem is in your html

Comment: In this page: [http://nsccplus.businesscatalyst.com/page2.html](http://nsccplus.businesscatalyst.com/page2.html) there is one link with the `next` class, so the pagination works

Comment: in the page http://nsccplus.businesscatalyst.com/page2.html there is still appearing nothing. only the ajax loader icon and then the message "load more data".

Comment: and i added the class next to my http://nsccplus.businesscatalyst.com/highlights-1 page. its the same as the other page. Can you please tell me what am i doing wrong as i cant figure it out.